# Using ThinkingSphinx, How to query min and max weight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I want to retrieve the `min(weight())` and `max(weight())` using `ThinkingSphinx`. I tried this:

```
results = Work.search(
            'example', :ranker => "expr('sum((4*lcs+2*(min_hit_pos==1)+exact_hit)*user_weight)*1000+bm25*20')",
            :select => 'min(weight()) as min_weight, max(weight()) as max_weight')
results.context[:panes] << ThinkingSphinx::Panes::WeightPane
```

Which translates to this sphinx expression:

```
SELECT min(weight()) as min_weight, max(weight()) as max_weight 
FROM `work` 
WHERE MATCH('example') 
LIMIT 0, 20 
OPTION ranker=expr('sum((4*lcs+2*(min_hit_pos==1)+exact_hit)*user_weight)*1000+bm25*20')
```

If I run the sphinx expression above against sphinx directly it works, however the `Work.search` call errors:

```
undefined method `constantize' for nil:NilClass
```

After looking at the code base, I see that the error is related to not having `sphinx_internal_class` in the `:select` clause and further to this, I now understand that this will be a problem because ThinkingSphinx wants to query `ActiveRecord` etc.

So my question:

**Is it possible with ThinkingSphinx to simply return back the raw sphinx query results and avoid querying `ActiveRecord` after the sphinx query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/thinking-sphinx/6zWjRB28-JM/nCx7CI33iykJ):

> Perform a standard TS search, but use the ‘raw’ middleware set (which
>   doesn’t translate Sphinx results into ActiveRecord objects):
>
> ```
> results = Model.search ‘foo’, :middleware =>
>               ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::RAW_ONLY
> ```

So changing to this gave me the raw results:

```
results = Work.search(
        'example', :ranker => "expr('sum((4*lcs+2*(min_hit_pos==1)+exact_hit)*user_weight)*1000+bm25*20')",
        :select => 'min(weight()) as min_weight, max(weight()) as max_weight'),
        :middleware => ThinkingSphinx::Middlewares::RAW_ONLY
```